# How to create regular expression that swaps lastname, firstname middle initial

Tags: regex, replace, expression

I'm trying to write a regular expression that swaps lastname, firstname middleinitial to firstname lastname.

so, for example

```
 doe, john j
    another example: 
 doe, jane
```

becomes

```
john doe
   2nd example results
jane doe
```

I've tried this: `(\w+?), (.+?)(&|-) ((\w+?),(.+?)(&|-))*(.+)` and this: `^(\w+), *([\w \.]+)[ ]+-[ ]*(.*)`

Neither work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you provide more examples of input strings that should be matched too? You seem to want to allow `&` and `-` chars too.

Comment: i've added another example.. it will always be lastname, firstname but some have lastname, firstname middle initial. Not all have middle initial. I'm trying to get the results to be firstname lastname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `^([a-zA-Z]+?),\s*([a-zA-Z]+?)(\s+[a-zA-Z])?$` by `$2 $1` should suit your needs.

Note that I didn't use the `\w` class since it matches underscores (`_`) and digits too, and I've never seen someone whose name is `John_ D0e` yet `;)`

Answer (score 0):

May be this might help:

```
perl -e '$name = "doe, john j"; $name =~ /(.*?), (.*)/is; $fname = $2; $lname = $1; $fname =~ s/\s.*//is; $name = $fname. " " . $lname; print "$name\n";'
```

Comment: For the other example you gave: perl -e '$name = "doe, john"; $name =~ /(.*?), (.*)/is; $fname = $2; $lname = $1; $fname =~ s/\s.*//is; $name = $fname. " " . $lname; print "$name\n";'